# Write this statement in a comprehensive way

Tags: python, syntax

Im starting to learn Python and programming in general. While doing a statements assessment test, I ran into a syntax problem that has no sense to me. I get a syntax error in the second for.

Thank you!

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
listst = st.split()
for word in listst:
    if word[0] == 's':
        print(word)
#in one sentence?
startwiths = [word if word[0] == 's' for word in listst]
```

Comment: The if condition goes after the for loop

Comment: The original loop doesn't build a list, so *it* shouldn't be replaced with a list comprehension at all. Using a list comprehension to build a list of words starting with "s" is fine, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
startwiths = [word for word in listst if word[0] == 's']
```

More info about list comprehensions in python can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Consider using `str.lower()`

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement goes at the end of a list comprehension. So rewrite your last line to be:

```
startwiths = [word for word in listst if word[0] == 's']
```

You can also further simplify you code by replacing `word[0] == 's'` with the builtin string `startswith` function:

```
startwiths = [word for word in listst if word.startswith('s')]
```

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
list_comp=[word for word in listst if word.lower()[0]=='s']
```

You can also use `.startswith`

```
list_comp=[word for word in listst if word.lower().startswith('s')]
```